# WPF from F# - reacting to event

Tags: wpf, f#

I am having trouble with the following example (slightly modified from the Expert F# book)

```
open System.Windows
open System.Windows.Controls
open System.Windows.Shapes
open System.Windows.Media
open System

let contentInit =
    let w = new Window(Topmost=true)
    let c = new Canvas()
    w.Content <- c

    let e = new Ellipse(Width=150., Height=150., Stroke=Brushes.Black)
    c.Children.Add(e) |> ignore

    e.MouseLeftButtonUp.Add(fun _ -> 
                                    e.Fill <- Brushes.Red
                                )
    w

let a = new Application()

[<EntryPoint>]
[<STAThread>]
let main (args: string []) =
    let myWin = contentInit
    do a.Run(myWin) |> ignore
    1
```

The behaviour that I expect is that the Ellipse is coloured red when (left) clicked, but nothing happens when the ellipse is clicked. What could be the problem here you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that your ellipse has no fill - try hitting the Black-parts or use

```
let e = new Ellipse(Width=150., Height=150., Stroke=Brushes.Black, Fill = Brushes.White)
```

if the fill is Null no Hittest will be executed - you have to give it some color (even transparent) to work this way.

Comment: Indeed, after adding this it works exactly as expected, thanks for help!